# Source location for variables that can be change e.g background-color - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme, css, variables

Sorry for the simply question,

I've seen in several posts that people have made a new theme and changed say the background of the homepage and would like to know where these variables are located. I know you have to make a new .less file however i'm unsure of how to correctly call variables to change aspects of my page.

How do you know the name of the variables, for example, the'background-color'? Where are the source files located?

Comment: I found some more paths where less variables are stored, please check edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact path would depend on whether you've installed magento using composer or web setup.

If you've used web setup, the files will be located here -

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/web/css/source
```

and for composer installation they will be here -

```
app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/web/css/source
```

most of the variable of value will be located in (I think you can extrapolate relative paths for following for composer installation)

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/web/css/source/_variables.less
```

and

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/web/css/source/_theme.less
```

If you are extending Magento Blank theme instead of luma, you might wanna look here instead

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/
```

**EDIT :**

After some further digging more variables can be found here -

```
vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/
```

and for composer installation,

```
lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/
```

Comment: I can change the background colour but not another variable i have changed in vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/web/css/source. See my edit

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple issues in same question. This is a different  issue, please post a separate question for it.

Comment: Its the same vein, just curious to know if i'm using the variable is all :)

Comment: Np, let me look into it, also please accept the answer as it solved your original issue.

Comment: Cheers mate - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/239397/am-i-changing-the-theme-correctly