# Am I changing the theme correctly?

Tags: magento2, theme, css

I'm trying to customise my theme but only a few variables seem to be displayed on my web page. I'm not sure that I am using the variables in vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/web/css/source . Any help would be much appreciated.

My .less file

```
@oh-my-blue:#FFC0CB;  
@green:#7CFC00;
body
{
background-color:@oh-my-blue;  <-- Works
border-color:@green;            <-- Doesn't Works
link__color:@green;              <-- Doesn't Works

}
```

Comment: Where are you changing this code?

Comment: app\code\Pulsestorm\StartingWithLess\view\frontend\web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its unclear exactly what you are trying to do.

`link__color:@green;` is bad `less` because `link__color: #7CFC00;` is invalid `css`. It won't break anything as far as I know but neither will it do anything.

If you are trying to change your `@link__color` variable, you would do the following `@link__color:@green;` (outside of the `body {}` delcaration)

The reason your `border-color` doesn't work, I suspect, is because your body element most likely doesn't have a border. Again I think you were trying to change a variable.

Treat your less like css and you should be ok, variables are for convenience but in my opinion just writing css is sometimes easier. I get the impression you may need to clarify your understanding of css first, I would start there and just stick to `css` before getting into writing `less`.